# How to make GDB format half-word memory as hex?

Tags: gdb

I'm working with an algorithm that uses `uint16_t` as the datatype. There are 4 half words in the array so I am trying to display the four half words in hex. I have not done anything other than `x/4h`:

```
(gdb) x/4h master_key
0x7fffffffd330: u"Āईᄐᤘ桷"
0x7fffffffd33c: u"桷敥\xbe0@"
0x7fffffffd346: u""
0x7fffffffd348: u"ꆋ翿"
```

According to the [GDB | Memory](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Memory.html):

> f, the display format
>
> The display format is one of the formats used by print (‘x’, ‘d’, ‘u’, ‘o’, ‘t’, ‘a’, ‘c’, ‘f’, ‘s’), and in addition ‘i’ (for machine
>   instructions). The default is ‘x’ (hexadecimal) initially. The default
>   changes each time you use either x or print.

I'm not sure why `x` is trying to print strings but I would like it to print the half words in hex.

GDB does not seem to be following the manual. I think I need to change the behavior of `x` and make it persistent. How do I tell GDB to print the half words in hex?

---

The following in in my `.gdbinit` but it looks like GDB is ignoring it ([not a surprise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44015338/608639)).

```
(gdb) shell cat ~/.gdbinit
set output-radix 16

set history save on
set history size 256

set logging on
set logging overwrite on
```

Comment: Try `x/4hx master_key` instead. If you only specify a width but don't specify a datatype, GDB will use the previous datatype. The first `x` is "eXamine memory". The `4` indicates "four elements". The `h` indicates "halfword" (16-bit) elements. The second `x` indicates heXadecimal. On a related note, you may print a 16-byte "string" in hexadecimal using `x/16bx` .